# Set index in Nuxt to other place

Tags: nuxt.js

By default, Nuxt will set index to pages/index.vue . In my case, I want to set pages/course/index.vue as my index. How can I do this? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by index? You want when someone load your domain.com it goes to domain.com/course ?

Comment: @Aldarund , Yes, it is my question :D

Comment: You should solve this at reverse proxy level e.g. nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by moving file index.html to /public then in next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/index.html',
      },
    ];
  },
};
```